# Vaadin 14 Lazy Loading Grid Error on implement CallbackDataProvider

Tags: java, lazy-loading, vaadin, java-ee-8

I have an error like this:

[image]

and here is my code :

```
CallbackDataProvider<AccountModel, Void> accountDataProvider = DataProvider
          .fromCallbacks(query -> accountServices.getAccountTable(
                    query.getOffset(), query.getLimit()
          ), accountServices.getAccountTableCount());
```

and here is the services code:

```
public List<AccountModel> getAccountTable(int offset, int limit) throws JsonProcessingException, EndpointException {
    List<AccountModel> datalog = new JsonResponseReader(restMockvaEndpoint.send(new EndpointRequestBuilder()
            .method("GET")
            .resource("/account")
            .property("offset", offset)
            .property("limit", limit)
            .build()
    )).getContentTable(AccountModel.class).getData();
    return datalog;
}
    
public int getAccountTableCount() throws JsonProcessingException, EndpointException {
    int datalog = new JsonResponseReader(restMockvaEndpoint.send(new EndpointRequestBuilder()
            .method("GET")
            .resource("/account")
            .build()
    )).getContentTable(AccountModel.class).getData().size();
    return datalog;
}
```

it's seems the error from `getAccountTableCount()` method that can't implement to `CallbackDataProvider`. Any idea?

Thank you.

Comment: The fetch callback must return Stream.

Comment: Can you please explain it? Or give me a link as reference or example. Thank you

Comment: I'm new in vaadin and java btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CallbackDataProvider<AccountModel, Void> accountDataProvider = 
    DataProvider
      .fromCallbacks(
          query -> accountServices.getAccountTable(
                query.getOffset(), query.getLimit()).stream(), 
        query -> accountServices.getAccountTableCount());
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still got the same error.

Comment: Oh I missed something. Checkout my updated answer

Comment: Thank you! It's a great answer. Now I must think about the exception bcs my services throws an exception

Comment: You should handle the exceptions in the service